# External iFrame Hidden Until Window Resize

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, shopify

*EDIT: Further inspection makes me think this is a Chrome/Firefox/Edge Mac issue. On Windows, Android and iOS it's fine. It looks like the iFrame that is brought in by the Javascript has it's height set to 0px, and only when you resize the window does Chrome 'wake up' and resize it to something more appropriate in order to display the iFrame contents.*

We're using Shopify's 'Buy Button' on our Webflow eCommerce store, however in this situation some Shopify buttons/prices won't display on desktop (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) unless you resize the window.

Here's what I believe to be going on on page load:

1. The Shopify buttons script runs loading in the prices
2. This particular page uses a script to move one Collection into another
3. This script runs, perhaps hiding the external iFrame from Shopify?
4. Chrome/Firefox/Edge are then unable to see the prices for these 'moved' items

I've spent all day looking for a solution. It seems likely it's down to the external iFrame. A couple of ideas I'm thinking out loud:

- Remove the iFrame?
- Delay the script load until the Collection move script is complete?
- Resize the iFrame after load to 'nudge it'?

Here's an example page (go to page 4 onwards to see the problem): https://golden-moments-usa.webflow.io/code-test

Here's the Shopify button code I'm using:

```html
<div id='product-component-{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;product-component-2&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Number&quot;\} }}'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.defer = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'golden-moments-usa.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: '7d944d2e69bddb24e7c33ba1395129bd',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: '{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;product-id&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Number&quot;\} }}',
        node: document.getElementById('product-component-{{wf {&quot;path&quot;:&quot;product-component-2&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Number&quot;\} }}'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
          
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "calc(25% - 20px)",
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-bottom": "50px"
        },
        "text-align": "left"
      },
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Lato, sans-serif",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "width": "100%",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "background-color": "#a81f33"
        },
        "background-color": "#ed2a47",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#13308a"
        },
        "border-radius": "8px",
        "padding-left": "30px",
        "padding-right": "30px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px"
      },
      "price": {
         "font-family": "Lato, serif",
        "font-weight": "700",
        "font-size": "20px",
        "color": "#4d4d4d"
      },
      "compareAt": {
        "font-family": "Lato, serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "color": "#0b1c51"
      }
    },
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": false,
      "title": false,
      "options": false,
      "price": true
    },
    "googleFonts": [
      "Lato"
    ]
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "imgWithCarousel": false,
      "button": true,
      "buttonWithQuantity": false
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Lato, sans-serif",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "background-color": "#ed2a47"
        },
        "background-color": "#0b1c51",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#13308a"
        },
        "border-radius": "8px",
        "padding-left": "30px",
        "padding-right": "30px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "cart": {
    "styles": {
      "button": {
        "font-family": "Lato, sans-serif",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "background-color": "#a81f33"
        },
        "background-color": "#ed2a47",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#13308a"
        },
        "border-radius": "8px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "total": "Subtotal"
    },
    "contents": {
      "note": true
    }
  },
  "toggle": {
    "styles": {
      "toggle": {
        "font-family": "Lato, sans-serif",
        "background-color": "#ed2a47",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#a81f33"
        },
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#13308a"
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        ":hover": {
          "color": "#c8ad76"
        }
      },
      "iconPath": {
        "fill": "#ffffff"
      }
    }
  }
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

And here's a short animation of what's happening:

[DOM hidden until resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwyZk.gif)